# Ubuntu Questions - Security - Concerns

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I have a few questions that I would like to verify. I currently have a Ubuntu VM on my windows host. I am opening it up Port Forwarding so host a gitlab repo on it. I would like to be able to access this repo anywhere online.
My concerns are of course security.
I have enabled my UFW and only added the SSH to it.
So without doing anything by default everything else incoming should be getting denied? that is my first question. Or do I have to actually say "ufw default deny incoming"
Next question I have iptables logging my port that I am running gitlab on.
I added a iptables rule to allow traffic to that specific port.
With that being said, no one should be able to remotely connect to any other program on my VM except my ssh port and my port for this program correct? I shouldnt have any worries about anything because I only have 2 ports allowing incoming traffic.
I also did some linux hardening techniques
Is there anything else I should be concerned about?
I have tried using my ipaddress with this port I opened but was unable to access this on the web. It works internal fine.

Any other concerns or suggestions I would love to hear. I am new to this.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UFW, which is an iptables frontend, is by default on

`xx` -- `DENY` --> `PC`

`PC` -- `ALLOW` --> `xx`

So yes, only the 2 ports that you've allowed in UFW will be accessible outside of the machine

Comment: By default, UFW is available but **not enabled** on most installations.  OP simply has to do `ufw enable` and set up UFW rules and then they will be fine from 'other ports' perspective.  However, there are a lot of other 'security' hardening tasks they can do.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about ports being open, you can use another (Linux-based) computer and perform a port scan of your server using `nmap`.  See [this](https://nmap.org/book/port-scanning-tutorial.html) for a quick tutorial or just Google for `nmap` to see the many tutorials out there.

I presume you're accessing your repository by private/public key pair?  If you're not, there are many tutorials out there; see [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-18-04-setup-ssh-public-key-authentication/) for some help on:

1. creating a private/public key pair
2. disallowing passwords and
3. configuring the server to allow private/public keys

Are you connected to a router?  If so, there may be port forwarding, etc. that you need to set up on that as well.  And that includes keeping its firmware up-to-date.

Lastly, my personal opinion is if you are worried about security, don't put something valuable on it.  System security also comes with experience and making mistakes...  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I have heard of nmap before. I have never used it tho, this sounds like a great reason to learn this program that I hear is an excellent resource. Yes I am using a router. I set up port forwarding on it with the port i opened and my internal ip. I went to a outside network and typed in my external ip (myip.com or etc) myip:port and I wasnt able to access my repo. I do not have ssh keys set up on my repo yet but I will set them up thats a great idea!

Comment: My main worry was if any1 outside could access any other programs on my VM or internal network other devices if I open up port forwarding to this 1 device and only 1 port.

Comment: The router is supposed to protect your network by adding that extra layer.  Obviously, by enabling port forwarding, you've opened up a path from the outside to your VM.  You do want to check your router to make sure nothing else is opened up; I find many configuration menus for routers to be really obscure, so just check all of the menus to make sure it's all good and keep the firmware updated.  Then, you just need to make sure the server is secure.  Some people suggest changing the default ssh port from 22 to something else.  I don't know if that really helps, but you can think about it.

Comment: @Bigbear For example, see [this](https://www.ubuntu18.com/ubuntu-change-ssh-port/).  You're not really improving security...you're just obscuring it.  But I've heard more than one person suggest it before to me...

Comment: yup, on my hardening tutorial I read that was 1 of the things it had me to. was change my default ssh port.

Comment: So Last night I got my site/port forwarding to the Internet to work! I checked my logs my repo/site was up less than 24 hours. I had a few IPs i didnt know, they came from: Russia and China. I also used nmap only my correct ports are open on the vm. Do I have anything to worry about since only I have my gitlab private repo up on the internet. they shouldnt be able to see anything else on my vm or my network. this is the only rule portforward on my router. I'm happy I finally have my repo up. Next I a plan  on hosting a website from my vm. I'm setting up multiple tools of security.

Comment: @Bigbear If you decide to put your VM on a public IP address, you're going to get people trying to get in several times a day or an hour.  There are many bored people out there...  If you're worried, I suggest installing `tripwire`...  As for a web site, the security of things like WordPress and Joomla are very poor.  Or, to be precise, they are ok, but some of the add-ons may be out-dated and pose a security risk.  Keep the add-ons to a minimum and to the latest versions.  Better yet, use a static site generator like `hugo` or `mkdocs`, if you don't need anything dynamic.

Comment: my website is going to be in .net core. I been developing it and going to host it in a docker container.
Currently I am hosting a private gitlab repo that I want to keep my code in. I want it private so I can access it or people I want to access it can. That is why I wanted to try self hosting. I am logging all traffic and only allowing specific ports through IPTables. Im assuming doing this will keep my safe. I only want access to those applications on the web. Everything else on my vm I dont want people to be able to access. As long as only the open ports are only thing seen ill be happy.

Comment: @Bigbear I see.  In that case, you will be fine!  Indeed, you were always talking about ports and I shifted you into CMS security -- sorry!  Indeed, I've managed a WordPress site that was hacked before and it's highly stressful.  Do protect your site with a password, at least.  Good luck!